# How can I move "index.html" when using webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webpack-dev-server

**Generally,when will "index.html" be loaded using webpack?**

**I want to move "index.html" to in build/.**

I'm in trouble over data flow from npm start using webpack.

In package.json, "start" is defined as:

```
"node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js".
```

However,I couldn't find where it would jump from "webpack-dev-server.js".

I found two description about "index.html" in it as below:

```
     .boolean("history-api-fallback").describe("history-api-fallback", "Fallback to /index.html for Single Page Applications.")
```

and

```
    console.log("404s will fallback to %s", options.historyApiFallback.index || "/index.html");
```

when I try moving "index.html" to in build/, browser returned "Cannot Get error".

**"index.html" and webpack.config.js are in same folder now.**

```
    ./  index.html  package.json  src/    test/
    ../  build/  node_modules/  public/   style/             
    webpack.config.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to update the script (in package.json) so it copies `index.html` to the destination folder:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base src",
  "build": "node node_modules/.bin/webpack && cp src/index.html build/index.html"
}
```

`npm run build` should now also copy `src/index.html` to `build/index.html`.

Comment: It worked! I could load "index.html" by using only "--content-base"  option.  Build by cp went well too, but  couldn't tell the result which was from build folder. However, it doesn't matter at all!  Thank you!

Comment: `&& cp src/index.html build/index.html` is a nice, simply hack, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a `webpack` expert, but I faced the same issue, and was able to solve it using a plugin: [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin)

First install it: `npm install html-webpack-plugin --save-dev`

Then edit your `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    //Your config here (entry, module, resolve, etc.)
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './build' //Or any other path you build into
    },
    plugins: [
        //other plugins if any
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.template.html', //your template file
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body'
        })
    ]
};
```

This is going to copy your `index.template.html` to `./build/index.html` and serve files from there.
It will also inject all assets at the bottom of the `<body>` tag.
You can further costumize this setup to fit your need of course, just [refer to the plugin docs](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/README.md).